# Knockout-kendo.js Dropdown Groupitems

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am trying to figure out how to group inside a combobox rendered using knockout-kendo.js. Here is my current code iteration.

```
<input data-bind="kendoComboBox:
    {
        data: AllCompetitors,
        dataTextField: 'Name',
        dataValueField: 'Id',
        index: 0,
        group: { field: 'group' },
        placeholder: 'Choose a competitor...'
    }
    " />
```

This renders the dropdown as expected except without the grouping that I was expecting. Is there something odd that I have to do as well with knockout-kendo.js to get this working or is it not supported? This works if it is just kendoUI and can't seem to find any examples online.

Additionally, I will want to select a predetermined option as well as bind this to a second dropdown.

I have set up a fiddle with an HTML Select with grouping and a sample of code that is expected to run this dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that the KnockoutKendoJS signature for this method is

```
kendoCombobox
```

Where the b is lowercase. This is unlike the signature in the kendo library